# Regexp hangs when input string contains brackets

Tags: ruby, regex

I have:

```
vv = /added:\s{0,}\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|terminated:\s{0,}\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|(?-mix:\((\w+([\p{P}\s]{,3}\w*)*)\))/i
```

Below is my experiment:

```
detail = "(value containts lorem ipsum lorum ipsum"
detail =~ vv
```

When I try without bracket at the start of input string, it works.

```
detail = "value containts lorem ipsum lorum ipsum"
detail =~ vv
# => nil
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316284/why-regex-ismatch-hangs

Comment: @sawa : my subject itself tell the question. I dont want to write it again inside the body content. Still you are not understanding please leave it.

Comment: @UriAgassi: Thanks for the related question.

Comment: Your `\w+([\p{P}\s]{,3}\w*)*` causes an issue. Try replacing it with `\w+(?:[\p{P}\s]{1,3}\w+)*`,or even `\w+(?:\W{1,3}\w+)*`.

Comment: see http://rubular.com/r/iu44Cy5b85

Answer (score 1):

The problem you experience is *catastrophical backtracking*. Your `\w+([\p{P}\s]{,3}\w*)*` causes an issue as the `([\p{P}\s]{,3}\w*)*` contains a nested zero or more quantifier `*`. The problem arises because the parts inside are both optional (=can match empty strings) and quantified. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU3hG4/1), try adding one more symbol and see the step amount increase: adding a space after `(value containt` will double the number of steps from 65,742 to 102,610! Adding 1 more symbol crashes the demo.

Replacing it with `\w+(?:[\p{P}\s]{1,3}\w+)*`, or even `\w+(?:\W{1,3}\w+)*` should fix the issue as the subpatterns inside the grouping `(...)` construct will no longer be matching empty strings (but the whole group will be optional, zero or more repetitions). `[\p{P}\s]{1,3}` requires at least 1 punctuation or whitespace and `\w+` requires one or more word characters.

Also note that you do not need the `(?-mix:...)` group, I removed it from my suggested pattern: you have no `.` inside (no need for `m`), no letters that can be in lower- or upper case (no need for `i`) and there are no spaces to ignore in the pattern (no need for `x`). Also, `{0,}` quantifier is equal to `*`, I replaced one or two in the beginning.

Use

```
vv = /added:\s*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|terminated:\s*\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|\((\w+(?:[\p{P}\s]{1,3}\w+)*)\)/i
detail = "(value containts lorem ipsum lorum ipsum"
detail =~ vv
```

See [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/mI2Ve2)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Will it give the same output as the old one ?

Comment: I think it should. The explanation of the suggested subpattern is given in a descriptive way, here is a concise version: *`\w+(?:\W{1,3}\w+)*` will match 1+ word characters followed with zero or more sequences of 1 to 3 non-word characters followed with 1+ word characters*. The version with `[\s\p{P}]` matches 1 to 3 punctuation or spaces. Compare it with yours (you have not provided any requirements, I deduced them from the pattern).